# DHTMLX Scheduler MVC parse function triggers a Get Request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, scheduler, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have a Timeline Scheduler and have created a **previous** and **next** buttons so that the user can navigate through the dates. To do that, I use this to jump to the selected date:

```
scheduler.updateView(selectedDate)
```

And then created a Get request to the controller action `Data` to retrieve the set of events of that specific date and of specific employee:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '@Url.Action("Data", "RO")',
   dataType: 'html',
   data: { employeeId: empid sDate: selectedDate},
   success: function (jsonObj) {
        scheduler.clearAll(); //clears all events
        scheduler.parse(jsonObj, "json"); //renders the new set of events (jsonObj)
});
```

This works fine. I can see the events for the specific date. But under the covers, this series of functions triggers the controller action `Data` **trice**!

The reason is, the scheduler function **updateView()** and **parse()** calls the controller action `Data` by default and I dont want that because it causes the triple posting.

Is there a way to prevent those two from triggering that ajax request?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer. When I was starting with DHTMLX scheduler for MVC, I added this line of code so that the scheduler will load the date I specified and not all the events in the database:

```
sched.EnableDynamicLoading(SchedulerDataLoader.DynamicalLoadingMode.Day);
```

Since we handled the 'load-specific-date-only' rule on our select statement, the scheduler no longer needed this code. So when I commented it out, **updateView()** and **parse()** doesn't trigger an ajax request anymore.